# Compare columns in two sheets

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have two sheets in Excel that I am trying to compare. This is a bit convoluted so I hope my explanation is clear.

Sheet 1 is named 'mapping and Sheet 2 is named SOA

I would like to compare column D in 'mapping' to column A in 'SOA'

Where the value in column D of mapping is equal to the result in column A of 'SOA' I would like to enter the corresponding text info from column B of SOA into column E (which is blank) in 'mapping'

Column A in SOA is in ascending order while column D is not, and cannot be.

A sample for the data is:

Sheet 1 (Mapping)

```
A           B         C        D          E
                               A1.3
                               A1.1
                               A1.2
```

Sheet 2 (SOA)

```
A          B           C       D          E
A1.1       YES
A1.2       MAYBE
A1.3        NO
A1.4       IDK
```

The result I am looking for would give me:

Sheet 1 (Mapping)

```
A           B         C        D          E
                               A1.3       NO
                               A1.1      YES
                               A1.2      MAYBE
```

I have tried the following formulas but have not gotten any luck

=IF(COUNTIFS(('mapping'!D3:D466),=SOA!A4:A136",SOA!B4,""))
=IF('mapping'!$D3:$D466=SOA!$A4:$A136,SOA!$B4:$B136,"")

Comment: Any more info you can provide? I only know the basics of vlookup

Comment: [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) will do this.

Comment: IF(VLOOKUP('mapping'!D3)=SOA!$A4,SOA!$B4,"")) ... this told me 'too few arguments'

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(A2,'SOA'!A2:B500,2,FALSE)`

Comment: This worked Tim Williams, but many of the cells are showing N/A even when I can see that they are a 1 to 1 match, the data type is the same, no extra spaces or characters. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're getting N/A then there may be extra spaces or other non-obvious characters on either of the sheets.  I've never seen vlookup() fail when there was an actual match...

Comment: Make sure in vlookup to use definite addressing in defining the lookup range $a$2:$b$500 rather than a2:b500 so it is not altered by dragging

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got it working with a combo of all of this. Some of the issue was the nature of the data I received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I got it working with a combo of all of this. Some of the issue was the nature of the data I receive